# error while installing mesa in command 'make linux-x86'

Tags: 11.10, installation, mesa

```
nir@nir:~/Downloads/mesa-8.0$ make linux-x86
make default
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nir/Downloads/mesa-8.0'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nir/Downloads/mesa-8.0/src'
Making sources for linux-x86
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nir/Downloads/mesa-8.0/src/glsl'
flex --nounistd -oglcpp/glcpp-lex.c  glcpp/glcpp-lex.l
make[3]: flex: Command not found
make[3]: *** התיינבל םיללכ ןיא ךא ,`depend' תשרוד `default' הרטמ.  Stop. **//trnaslaet from hebrew: target 'default' Requires `depend' But there are no rules for building. Stop.**
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nir/Downloads/mesa-8.0/src/glsl'
make[2]: *** [subdirs] 1 הלקת **//trnaslaet from hebrew: fault**
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nir/Downloads/mesa-8.0/src'
make[1]: *** [default] 1 הלקת **//trnaslaet from hebrew: fault**
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nir/Downloads/mesa-8.0'
make: *** [linux-x86] 2 הלקת **//trnaslaet from hebrew: fault**
nir@nir:~/Downloads/mesa-8.0$
```

Is there any solution?
Thanks!

Comment: This is at least your second question with Makefile output in a different language. Please run `LANG=C make` instead of `make` to get English error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty obvious:

```
make[3]: flex: Command not found
```

Mesa has a build-dependency on `flex` which can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install flex
```

To install all build dependencies for Mesa at once, run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mesa
```

Comment: Thanks, the first command successed, but the second didn't. and after rebooting, videos in youtube seems to run slower, i think of installing ubuntu again ana ask her about the whole driver of my graphic card in my laptop

Comment: The second command just installs all build depenendecies which are **only** used when building (a.k.a. compiling) Mesa. It does not affect the Mesa version installed on the system. For a novice, I'd suggest not to mess around with mesa. Install the latest stable version to see if the issue sorts out (Oneiric 11.10 atm).

Comment: the second command, is i mean of the dri.  i got involved with the driver for my intel graphic card